# Scala - for loop on a string

Tags: string, scala, for-loop

In the scala REPL, when I give "H".toInt, I get NumberFormatException.  But, the same thing is working within the for loop - 
        for ( e  <- "Hello" ) println ( e.toInt)
I want to understand how it works within the for loop but not outside.

Comment: `"H"` is a `String`. `'H'` is a `Char` so `'H'.toInt` works fine.

Comment: As a minor technicality, Scala does have for loops and this is one because there's no `yield`: http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Scala can convert a Char to an Int, as you can see here:

```
scala> 'H'.toInt
res0: Int = 72
```

But there is no implicit conversion from String to Int

```
scala> "H".toInt
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "H"
```

In your for loop, you are assigning a `Char` to `e`.

Answer (score 5):

`"H"` is a `String`, while `e` is a `Char`, and the latter are *integer* values (*Unicode* code point values) that map to characters; calling `.toInt` on a `Char` value simply returns that code point value. A `String` is a sequence of `Char` values, and the `for` loop iterates on each character that makes up the string `"Hello"` in turn, processing them one at a time:

```scala
>scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_161).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> "H".toInt
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "H"
  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toInt(StringLike.scala:301)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toInt$(StringLike.scala:301)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:29)
  ... 28 elided

scala> for(e <- "Hello") println(e.toInt)
72
101
108
108
111
```

For example, `72` is the *Unicode* code point value for the character `'H'`, `101` for the character `'e'`, etc.

If you execute `'H'.toInt` it will work as it does in the `for` loop:

```scala
scala> 'H'.toInt
res2: Int = 72
```

When `toInt` is used on a `String`, if its value encodes an integer value, then it will work. For example:

```scala
scala> "72".toInt
res3: Int = 72
```

If it *doesn't* encode an integer value, then you get the `NumberFormatException`:

```scala
scala> "Fred".toInt
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Fred"
  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toInt(StringLike.scala:301)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toInt$(StringLike.scala:301)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:29)
  ... 28 elided
```